# Entity Framework child class, now requires Id/Key?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a child object in my entity framework model.  Something like this

```
public MyModel() {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyModelReference Reference { get; set; }
}

public MyModelReference() {
    public bool IsActive { get; set;}
    public bool Name { get; set;}
}
```

This works fine, in SQL it creates 1 table called MyModel, and in there i have the following columns

> Id
>
> Name
>
> Reference_IsActive
>
> Reference_Name

This is nice, because in my class, everything to do with Reference for MyModel I put within my MyModelReference class, and i can access those properties by accessing the Reference property within MyModel.  Nice and tidy.

Now i have other models in my library, and i would like to add a link between MyModel and MyOtherModel, but since this property is particular to Reference, i would like to add it to my MyModelReference class.  So i change it too something like this

```
public MyOtherModel() {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public MyModelReference() {
    public bool IsActive { get; set;}
    public bool Name { get; set;}
    public long OtherModelId { get; set; }
    public MyOtherModel OtherModel { get; set; }
}
```

Now for some reason, when i do this and run the command

```
-update-database
```

I get an error like so

EntityType 'ModelReference' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
ModelReferences: EntityType: EntitySet 'ModelReferences' is based on type 'ModelReference' that has no keys defined.

Why do i have to add a key to the child class, when the parent class has the Id/Key defined?  Has i set something up incorrectly?

I would expect this setup to give me a table with the following columns

> Id
>
> Name
>
> Reference_IsActive
>
> Reference_Name
>
> Reference_OtherModelId

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean?  I am using my own types?

Comment: By convention, a type that has no primary key specified is treated as a complex type. There are some scenarios where Code First will not detect a complex type. Please, try explicitly define your MyModelReference as Complex Type. On your model Configuration add: modelBuilder.ComplexType<MyModelReference>()

Comment: Go to your Context, find the OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) and add modelBuilder.ComplexType<MyModelReference>() .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a key defined on a type [EF will infer by convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx) that the type is a complex type, as it does with `MyModelReference`.

Unfortunately, you can't have associations/relationships on a complex type:

> Complex types cannot participate in associations. Neither end of an association can be a complex type, and therefore navigation properties cannot be defined on complex types.

*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee382831(v=vs.100).aspx*

Comment: There is no navigation properties in his model. There are a complex type.

Comment: No virtual modifier was defined.

Comment: @ViniciusGonçalves: I meant originally

Comment: It seems i want an association on a complex type, which aint possible.  Will have to change the ComplexType to be stored in a separate table instead.  Thanks @ViniciusGonçalves

Comment: @ViniciusGonçalves: a property doesn't need `virtual` to be a navigation property, removing `virtual` disables lazy loading.  (See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazyOffProperty))